# Pandas: how can I put in a set the elements grouped by groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following (example) dataset:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([["001", "Apple"],["002","Strawberry"],["001", None],["002","Strawberry"], ["003", "Apple"],["003","Strawberry"],], columns = ["Deal", "Product"])

  Deal     Product
0  001       Apple
1  002  Strawberry
2  001            
3  002  Strawberry
4  003       Apple
5  003  Strawberry
```

I would like to group in a set all the products linked to an order, like this:

```
  Deal              Product
0  001              {Apple}
1  002         {Strawberry}
2  003  {Strawberry, Apple}
```

I have an attempted solution as one of the answers below, I would like to understand if I am doing it in the right (pythonic, fastest) way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `notnull`:

```
print (df.loc[df['Product'].notnull()].groupby("Deal")["Product"].apply(set))

Deal
001                {Apple}
002           {Strawberry}
003    {Strawberry, Apple}
```

Use `df.loc[~df['Product'].isin([None,""])]...` if you want to take care of both `None` and `''`. Or use the methods from other answers for filtering.

Comment: To have a fair comparison, I've tested this solution adding the part that consider the special case `""` (after all everyone else did it). In terms of speed, this solution is on pair with Jezrael, but I think your answer is more clear and coincise (pythonic way yeeee)

Comment: @FedericoDorato - `df.loc[~df['Product'].isin([None,""])]` is more pythonic?

Comment: Then maybe `df.loc[~df['Product'].isin([None,np.nan,""])]` should be same output like `df[df['Product'].notna() & df['Product'].ne('')]`

Comment: @jezrael You have more right than me to define what is pythonic and whatnot, yet I find Henry's code easier to read and to comprehend on the spot. Given the same execution speed, I would totally go for his code, and this is what happened

Comment: @FedericoDorato - Ya, there is no clear state what is pythonic and not ;)

Answer (score 2):

Idea is remove missing values with chained [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with test no empty strings by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
mask = df['Product'].notna() & df['Product'].ne('')
df = df[mask].groupby('Deal')['Product'].agg(set).reset_index()
print (df)
  Deal              Product
0  001              {Apple}
1  002         {Strawberry}
2  003  {Apple, Strawberry}
```

Comment: To have a fair comparison, I've tested this solution without `reset_index()` (after all everyone else returned a Series and not a DF). In terms of speed, this solution is on pair with Henry, but I think his answer is more clear and coincise. +1 for the speed

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) with [`pd.Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) with `set`.

To delete `''` just use set difference here i.e `{1,2,3} - {3} = {1,2}`. So, `set(x.dropna())-{''}` would give a set without `''` after dropping all missing values.

```
df.groupby('Deal')['Product'].agg(lambda x:set(x.dropna())-{''})

Deal
001                {Apple}
002           {Strawberry}
003    {Strawberry, Apple}
Name: Product, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! In terms of speed, your solution works a little bit worse than the others. But it really elegant, +1

Comment: @FedericoDorato Thank you. If I could optimize `lambda x:set(x.dropna())-{''}` part it would more faster as this has no vectorization. Will try to come with something faster. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I started from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32967876/10254228) to solve my problem

```
# Turn every element in product in a set of one or zero elements
# Also Ensure we don't have null values
df["Product"] = df["Product"].apply(lambda val: {val} if val not in [None, ""] else {})
#Use the answer mentioned to bring together the single sets
df.groupby('Deal').agg({'Product':lambda x: set.union(*x)}).reset_index('Deal')
```

Final result:

```
>>> df
  Deal              Product
0  001              {Apple}
1  002         {Strawberry}
2  003  {Strawberry, Apple}
```